# Implement a protocol with a behaviour in a macro in Elixir

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I have a protocol that has a single function with a relatively complex API:

```
defprotocol Foo do
  def complex(foo, x, y)
end
```

I want to provide a way to implement this protocol for a common and simpler use case. After some experimentation, I came up with the following:

```
defmodule Bar do
  @callback simple(any, any) :: boolean

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      @behaviour Bar

      defimpl Foo do
        # TODO this is really hacky. What is a better way to reference parent module?
        # Note that the 1 in drop(1) is from Foo's module name
        @parent_module __MODULE__ |> Module.split |> Enum.drop(1) |> Module.concat
        def complex(bar, x, _y) do
          matches = @parent_module.simple(bar, x)
          if matches, do: [x], else: []
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can implement Foo via `use Bar`, but the way that `@parent_module` is determined and used seems wrong. Is there a better way than using the hack in the `TODO` above? What is the idiomatic way to do this? I would rather not turn `Foo` into a behaviour because dispatch and consolidation of protocols fits the usage pattern.

Comment: I don't really see the problem your trying to solve. Can you provide a complex and simple use case? What's confusing me is the use of defimpl without the `for: ` option.

Comment: The `for` parameter defaults to the module in which the `defimpl` is defined

Comment: Why doesn't just `__MODULE__` work?

Comment: @StevePallen inside the impl, `__MODULE__` is `<parent module>.<protocol module>`.

Comment: Thanks guys. I learned two two things from this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get and store the parent module's name in a local variable, then put it in an attribute in the implementation and then use it:

```
defmodule Bar do
  @callback simple(any, any) :: boolean

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      @behaviour Bar

      parent_module = __MODULE__

      defimpl Foo do
        @parent_module parent_module

        def complex(bar, x, _y) do
          matches = @parent_module.simple(bar, x)
          if matches, do: [x], else: []
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Great! Is the `parent_module` variable actually present in the resulting module that is generated, or is it only present in the macro? I ask because I thought you couldn't declare variables like that in modules that aren't module attributes.

Comment: It will be in the generated code but because of macro hygiene, it wouldn't be accessible from the remaining parts of the calling module with the name `parent_module`. And it won't be present at runtime, only at compile time.